# How to store array of posts in Swift, even after app relaunch?

Tags: arrays, swift, uicollectionview

I'm trying to store an array of posts, a custom class I have defined. I would like to just add on to this array after every relaunch of the app, rather than fetch all the posts again.

How do I persist this array even after relaunch of the app? I know UserDefault is only for small amounts of data.

```
import UIKit
class HomeViewController: UICollectionViewController {

     private var posts = [Post]()

     override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()

          PostService.shared.fetchPosts { (newPosts) in
               self.posts.append(contentsOf: newPosts)
          }
     }
}
```

The problem I face now is that the posts array becomes empty on a relaunch of the application. So when I add new posts to the array, they become the only posts present, and the old posts are missing.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Save them in a file. Or use core data.

Comment: If Post conforms to Codable, you can use JSONEncoder/JSONDecoder to save and load from file.

Then when you go to fetch posts, you can first check to see if anything is saved to disk.

Comment: You could put it in a JSON and read it from the JSON and modify it. This tutorial is really helpful. https://swift.programmingpedia.net/en/tutorial/223/reading-writing-json